# adding or removing from an observable collection within ForEach

Tags: c#, mvvm, observablecollection

I don't think I can modify the observable collection 'varieties' in the foreach loop below - whenever the conditions in the 'if' are met the 'Remove' happens then the foreach exists when it still has the bulk of the collection to go through.

I changed it so that if the condition was met rather than remove from varieties it adds the variety to a new list, but again as soon as the condition is met for the first time the foreach exist.

Am I missing something?

```
foreach (Variety variety in varieties)
 {
     if (variety.Type != main.Type && variety.Type != null)
      {
           varieties.Remove(variety);
       }
 }
```

changed code:

```
foreach (Variety variety in varieties)
 {
     if (variety.Type == main.Type || variety.Type == null)
      {
           FilteredVarieties.Add(variety);
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the source collection inside the foreach. If you really want to modify ,try having a copy to loop in foreach and modify it inside.

```
 var sourcecopy=varieties;
 foreach (Variety variety in sourcecopy)
 {
 if (variety.Type != main.Type && variety.Type != null)
  {
       varieties.Remove(variety);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove an item from your collection in a `foreach` loop.  What is going on when you say `foreach` is it is really creating a `for` loop that goes from 0 to the original count of the collection.  So once you remove something and the count of the collection changes, the range for the loop does not get updated.

If you switch to a normal `for` loop, you should be good though.

Answer (score 0):

As others (and the compiler) have probably said, you can't change a collection that you are enumerating through in that way. However, if you `.ToList()` your collection in the `foreach` definition, you are actually enumerating a copy of your list, so are free to remove or add to your original list.

```cs
foreach (Variety variety in varieties.ToList())
{
    if (variety.Type != main.Type && variety.Type != null)
    {
         varieties.Remove(variety);
    }
}
```